# CNN accuracy on binary classification of cat/dog images no better than random

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I've adapted a simple CNN from a tutorial on [Analytics Vidhya](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/06/architecture-of-convolutional-neural-networks-simplified-demystified/).

Problem is that my accuracy on a holdout set is no better than random.  I am training on ~8600 images each of cats and dogs, which should be enough data for decent model, but accuracy on the test set is at 49%.  Is there a glaring omission in my code somewhere?

```
import os
import numpy as np
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from datetime import datetime
from PIL import Image
from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical
from sklearn.utils import shuffle


def main():

    cat=os.listdir("train/cats")
    dog=os.listdir("train/dogs")
    filepath="train/cats/"
    filepath2="train/dogs/"

    print("[INFO] Loading images of cats and dogs each...", datetime.now().time())
    #print("[INFO] Loading {} images of cats and dogs each...".format(num_images), datetime.now().time())
    images=[]
    label = []
    for i in cat:
        image = Image.open(filepath+i)
        image_resized = image.resize((300,300))
        images.append(image_resized)
        label.append(0) #for cat images

    for i in dog:
        image = Image.open(filepath2+i)
        image_resized = image.resize((300,300))
        images.append(image_resized)
        label.append(1) #for dog images

    images_full = np.array([np.array(x) for x in images])

    label = np.array(label)
    label = to_categorical(label)

    images_full, label = shuffle(images_full, label)

    print("[INFO] Splitting into train and test", datetime.now().time())
    (trainX, testX, trainY, testY) = train_test_split(images_full, label, test_size=0.25)


    filters = 10
    filtersize = (5, 5)

    epochs = 5
    batchsize = 32

    input_shape=(300,300,3)
    #input_shape = (30, 30, 3)

    print("[INFO] Designing model architecture...", datetime.now().time())
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=input_shape))
    model.add(keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D(filters, filtersize, strides=(1, 1), padding='same',
                                                data_format="channels_last", activation='relu'))
    model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(keras.layers.Flatten())

    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(units=2, input_dim=50,activation='softmax'))
    #model.add(keras.layers.Dense(units=2, input_dim=5, activation='softmax'))

    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

    print("[INFO] Fitting model...", datetime.now().time())
    model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batchsize, validation_split=0.3)

    model.summary()

    print("[INFO] Evaluating on test set...", datetime.now().time())
    eval_res = model.evaluate(testX, testY)
    print(eval_res)

if __name__== "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Is it a binary classification or multi-class classification?

Comment: I do see that you are not shuffling the data. Since, you are first loading the data for cats and then for dogs, it is likely that during training, the network initially learns representation for Cats, and later for Dogs. But while   learning the representation for Dogs, the network gets optimized such that there were no Cats.

Comment: You are right.  I shuffled the data and re-ran. but the accuracy is still the same.  Updated the original code accordingly above

Comment: You're only doing 5 epochs...what happens if that number is 500? Typically you run until your error is an acceptable rate or the epoch count is big. You can't expect it to learn anything after only 5 iterations.

Comment: Number of epochs must not be the problem here.  That is 5 passes through ~16K images, with weights adjusted every 32 images.  This should be enough data for the network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me the problem comes from the size of your network, you have only one Conv2D with a filter size of 10. This is way too small to learn the deep reprensation of your image.

Try to increment this a lot by using blocks of common architectures like VGGnet !
Example of a block :

```
x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3) , padding='SAME')(model_input)
x = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.3)(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3) , padding='SAME')(x)
x = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.3)(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(x)
x = Dropout(0.25)(x)
```

You need to try multiple blocks like that, and increasing the filter size in order to capture deeper features.

Other thing, you don't need to specify the input_dim of your dense layer, keras automaticly take care of that !

Last but not least, you need to fully connected network in oder to correctly classify your images, not only a single layer.

For example :

```
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(256)(x)
x = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.3)(x)
x = Dense(128)(x)
x = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.3)(x)
x = Dense(2)(x)
x = Activation('softmax')(x)
```

Try those changes and keep me in touch !

## Update after op's questions

Images are complex, they contain much information like shapes, edges, colors, etc

In order to capture the maximum amont of information you need to passes through multiple convolutions which will learn the different aspects of the image.
Imagine that like for example first convolution will learn to recognise a square, the second conv to recognise circles, the third to recognise edges, etc ..

And for my second point, the final fully connected acts like a classifier, the conv network will output a vector that "represents" a dog or a cat, now you need to learn that this kind of vector is one class or the other one.
And directly feeding that vector in the final layer is not enough to learn this representation.

Is that more clear ?

## Last update for op's second comment

Here the two ways for defining a Keras model, both output the same thing !

```py
model_input = Input(shape=(200, 1))
x = Dense(32)(model_input)
x = Dense(16)(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
model = Model(inputs=model_input, outputs=x)




model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(32, input_shape=(200, 1)))
model.add(Dense(16, activation = 'relu'))
```

## Example of architecure

```py
model = Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D(32, (3,3), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D(32, (3,3), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D(64, (3,3), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D(64, (3,3), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(keras.layers.Flatten())

model.add(keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Don't forget to normalize your data before feeding into your network.

A simple `images_full = images_full / 255.0` on your data can boost your accuracy a lot.
Try it with grayscale images too, it's more computaly efficient.

Comment: I understand your first point. I'm highly suspicious, however, of the fact that even 1 conv2d layer with 10 filters doesn't get us any better than random guessing.  Remember. the model sees 16K of cats/dogs 5 times. Seems like enough data to deduce at least some patterns.  My hunch is that something is misspecified.  I'm reluctant to implement your suggestion before addressing this because I'm running this locally on my machine.  Regarding your second point, why do you need to have 2 additional dense layers before the final layer that has 2 nodes?

Comment: I updated my answer because the comment was too long !

Comment: Thanks.  Why do you have the x's at the end of the line?  Is that another way to specify additional layers?  I'm only familiar with the model.add syntax

Comment: Yeah exactly, you can specify keras layer with model.add and with the way i defined it. I will update my answer with a naïve example to show you !

Comment: Modified the script as per your suggestions (added just 1 more conv layer and 2 dense layers to start with).  Accuracy on test set is still at 50%.  I don't know what is going on.

Comment: I updated my answer with an architecture that's work

Comment: What accuracy are you getting on the test set?

Comment: More than 75% on 5 epochs, but i forgot a little thing, i updated my answer !

Comment: I'm getting around the same thing.  It seems that keeping the strides at (1,1), which is what the example on the site initially had, keeps the accuracy at random.  Why would that be?